# Masm32 - Addressing modes and arrays

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, addressing-mode

I am a bit confused by addressing modes.

```
 array1 DWORD 200 DUP(?)
```

If i have this statement:

```
mov EAX, [EBX + EDI + 10]
```

EBX is the base, EDI is the index, and + 10 is saying add ten more bytes to EDI? so, EDI would then return 14 bytes long?
and return the address and put it into EAX?

Similiarly,

```
mov EAX, [EBX + EDI * 4]
```

Is this saying that at what ever index in the array, returns 4 bytes long?
Because the array is 4 bytes long for each index right? I guess im not understanding what * 4 does!

in addition,

```
  mov ECX, 100 ; loop counter
  mov ESI, 0

  top1:

  mov [array1 + ESI * 4], ECX

  inc ESI

  loop top1
```

This would be putting the number 100 into the array starting at index zero 4 bytes big?
So, index[0] = 100, index[1]= 101, index[2]= 102?

Thank you

Comment: A `mov` like that doesn't put the address in the destination but the value at that address. If you want the address, that's what `lea` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov EAX, [EBX + EDI + 10]
```

Take the value in `EBX` and add the value in `EDI` and add 10, then use this result as an address to load a 32-bit value into `EAX`.

```
mov EAX, [EBX + EDI * 4]
```

Take the value in `EBX` and add to it 4 times the value in `EDI`, then use the result as an address to load a 32-bit value into `EAX`.

The last one stores a decreasing sequence of numbers starting at 100 into the memory locations starting at `array1`. `ECX` is decremented every time the `loop` instruction executes, until it reaches 0. The address each progressive value of `ECX` is stored at is `array1` plus 4 times `ESI`, which is incremented on every iteration.

Comment: What does 4 times the value in EDI really mean? if the value is 5 we times it by 4 so we would return 20? i dont see the point in doing this? Or are we reurning 4 bytes more starting at EDI index?

Comment: Exactly - if `EDI` is 5, indicating we want the 6th 32-bit integer, we need to add 5*4=20 to the base address (since the address points to a single byte of 8-bits, we need to multiply the index by 4 when dealing with 4-byte 32-bit quantities).